# Pop-up view controller not display on older devices Swift

Tags: swift, animation, popup, transparent

I have a link in my app on the home screen page. When I click this link on iPhone 11 Pro max, a pop-up with text and transparent background is displayed.
But the problem is on other devices: When I try it on etc.: iPhone 6s plus or 8, nothing happens.Thanks for any suggestions.

There is my code from home screen:

```
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    @IBAction func showPopup(_ sender: Any) {

            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
            self.addChild(popOverVC)
            popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)

        }
```

and there is code for pop-up view controller:

```
import UIKit

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

        self.showAnimate()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.removeAnimate()
        //self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
            }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                if (finished)
                {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Actual code:

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

     @IBAction func showPopup(_ sender: Any) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
        popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

        popOverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.bounds
           self.present(popOverVC, animated: true)

          /*
           self.addChild(popOverVC)
            popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
           */

        }

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle { return UIModalPresentationStyle.none }

    }
```

Comment: First It is not called pop-up, it is called popover. Second this is not how you should present a popover, you should set your popOverVC modalPresentationStyle to popover `popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover`, set its `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView =  view`, a sourceRect (which is the place on you view that you want it to be shown. `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = theTargetRectOnYourView` and then present it `present(popOverVC, animated: true)`

Comment: You might need to set its `preferredContentSize` before presenting it.

Comment: ok thanks for update, I try to change it in my code and let you know  solutions, thanks

Comment: Hi, I try this but with same results
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
     
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        let presentationController = controller.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController
        presentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        presentationController.sourceRect = view.bounds
        self.present(controller, animated: true)

Comment: add this to the view controller you `func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle { .none }` and also make it conform to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and add `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self` and for landscape add `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.overrideTraitCollection = .init(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)`

Comment: Do yo still need help with this?

Comment: Yes, I try this but still on 6s plus nothing happend + on 11 pro after close popover home screen stay grey:popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self  popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover popOverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)  let presentationController = popOverVC.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController presentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView presentationController.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds self.present(popOverVC, animated: true)

Comment: with this:  func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle { return UIModalPresentationStyle.none }

    }

Comment: Try setting the delegate after setting the popover modalPresentationStyle to `.popover`

Comment: Have you added `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` to your ViewCOntroller declaration?

Comment: If you create a sample project and zip it I can take a look at it if you don't figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean with this? Same results : popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        popOverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        let presentationController = popOverVC.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController
        presentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        presentationController.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
        self.present(popOverVC, animated: true)

Comment: Yes , here import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

Comment: kind of hard to read your code in comments but you don't need `let presentationController = popOverVC.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController` thats not what I have posted in comments

Comment: fix your code first reading my comments again, more specifically setting the sourceView and sourceRect, try it and if don't work let me know

Comment: for your sourceView you can set your viewController `view` or `viewWIndow` ==> `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view`

Comment: when setting the source rect you need to pass a frame inside your view frame. It is usually the frame of a cell or the frame of a button on a screen (or a frame of a tabbar or toolbar item) popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = theFrameOfTheCell or buttonFrame

Comment: so use it's frame as the sourceRect

Comment: Yes, I have button.UIButton, do you mean something like this?: popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = UIButton.init(frame:CGRect)

Comment: You need to get the frame of your button's instance. `yourButton.frame`

Comment: Ok I try it and let you know